# Linker problem in Release when trying to add GLUI library to project

Tags: c++, lnk2005

I try to add the GLUI library to my project.
Compiling in Debug mode runs fine. But if I compile in Release, it gives me a bunch of LNK2005 errors saying things like:

```
error LNK2005: _realloc already defined in Libcmt.lib(realloc.obj)
```

ok - i already got some similar Linker problems before because I use both CRT and MFC in my app but i could resolve this problem using this guide: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=http://support.microsoft.com:80/support/kb/articles/q148/6/52.asp&NoWebContent=1

therefore in my Project settings in the Linker->Input panel i have

```
additional dependencies: Nafxcw.lib Libcmt.lib
ignore libraries: Nafxcw.lib;Libcmt.lib
```

so - this used to work fine. but now that I added the glui32.lib (it actually gets loaded in the glui.h header using a #pragma statement) to my project, i get those linker errors.

Any advise on what I can do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is one linker option available in Visual Studio to supress these kind of linker errors. I mean, if the definition already exist in some other library it will give these kind of errors. Please refer MSDN for visual stuio linker options.